# How to act on a MainActivity object after the user has changed Preferences?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

**GOAL:** when the user change a preference in settings I would like to take an action on the main activity. 
In particular I need to change an HashMap.

**PROBLEM:** I can't find a solution. And I'm start thinking my approach is wrong upstream.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // db declaration //
    private SignalDatabase db;  

   private HashMap<Integer, String> RSSIcolorHmap ;





}
```

**SettingsActivity**

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     public  static class MainSettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

     public final static String KEY_ENABLE_BACKGROUND_UPDATE = "enable_background_update";
     public final static String KEY_ENABLE_LAST_KNOWN_LOCATION = "enable_last_known_location";
     public final static String KEY_DELETE_DB_DATA = "delete_db_data";
     public final static String KEY_CHANGE_MAP_COLOR ="change_map_color";

     private SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener preferenceChangeListener;
     @Override
     public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle bundle, String s) {
         // Load the Preferences from the XML file
         addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

         preferenceChangeListener = new 
        SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
             @Override
             public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {

                 if(key.equals(KEY_DELETE_DB_DATA))
                 {

                     String connectivityType = sharedPreferences.getString(key, null);
                     new DeleteAreaAsync(SignalAreaDatabase.getDatabase(getContext()), connectivityType).execute();

                 } else if(key.equals(KEY_CHANGE_MAP_COLOR)){

                     String gradientColor = sharedPreferences.getString(key, null);
                      /* I want to use this value to take action on MainActivity's HashMap. */

                }

            }
        };

    }

         }

    }
```

**WHAT I TRIED**

I've read around getting this two (non working) ideas:

**#1 METHOD**

```
SettingsActivity settingsActivity = (SettingsActivity)getActivity();
 MapsActivity mapsActivity = (MapsActivity) settingsActivity.getParent();
```

but `getParent()` always return `null`. From the android developer website:

> Return the parent activity if this view is an **embedded child**.

**#METHOD2**

```
 SettingsActivity settingsActivity = (SettingsActivity)getActivity();
     MapsActivity mapsActivity = (MapsActivity) settingsActivity.getCallingActivity();
```

But in this case `getCallingActivity()` return a `ComponentName` object from which I can't get a reference to the relative Activity.

**QUESTIONS:**

1) Is this approach totally wrong upstream? If yes how can I solve?

2) If not, is possible to make one of the two methods above work?

3) What exactly does it mean embedded child?

Comment: For me it is not apparent what the "why" is--just getting the `Activity`--Why?   How should the flow be? Why do you think you need the "calling Activity"

Comment: The flow is : MainActivity start SettingsActivity which starts the Fragment.
 I need to access to a method of the "settings Activity's calling Activity" (MainActivity)  while I'm in the Fragment. I don't know if is clear.

Comment: Yes, that is more clear, but I would suggest, that anything you need to access from an `Activity` that is deep down in the stack from another `Activity` should not be a member of an `Activity`. In most (if not all cases) trying to do something like `MainActivity.getThisData` or `MainActivity.getThisObject` from another `Activity` is bad practice.

Comment: @Barns why is bad practice?

Comment: Don't misuse an `Activity` class to access data or objects from other activities. An  `Activity` is for presenting information, not maintaining data references. Consider any pattern MVC, MVP or MVVM. All of these concepts are insist on a strict separation of data models and code. And for good reason this is best practice. Although MVC is a bit "outdated" in many applications it can still be quite effective.  Maybe read this :: https://academy.realm.io/posts/eric-maxwell-mvc-mvp-and-mvvm-on-android/

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `startActivityForResult()` in order to use `.getCallingActivity()`

... or add a `Bundle` to the `Intent`, which passes the name of the Activity.

`ComponentName` can used with `intent.setComponent(componentName)`.

Comment: But when I get the name of the Activity how can I get a reference to the Activity from the name?

Comment: why would you want to know that? you're probably working against the framework. you could even switch by request-code, and then get a handle with `SomeActivity.getInstance()` ...nevertheless, it sounds questionable.

Comment: Yes, I feel like it's damn wrong. 
I need to access a method (a getter) of that Activity. Which is the best practice in this case?

Comment: Send the value of the `getter` in the intent when starting SettingsActivity and then use it from there

Comment: @Maicake difficult to tell, while not knowing what the getter would return. passing it along with the intent sounds plausible for simple data-types (only). in the other direction, you could use an `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`.

Comment: @nupadhyaya as Martin points out passing the value to the Intent is feasible just for simple-type.

Comment: @Maicake you could use something alike `SignalDatabase.getInstance(mContext)` - which should return the instance of your implementation, or create a new one instance. it's only important to instance only a single instance of it.

Comment: I've already use singleton approach with the db. Should I use it for each object I need to call in another activity?

Comment: @Maicake this always depends on the use-case... in some situations one may want to obtain an already constructed instance - while in others one can construct a new instance and then destroy it again.

Comment: Let's say I want to have a single global instance of an obj that I initializa within OnCreate,  and I need to access  it in more activities. Are there other solution other than singleton approach?

Comment: @MartinZeitler I added more code could you tell me if "I'm working against the framework" , or in other words, if it's totally wrong XD.

Answer (score 0):

Your design is wrong.You can not access MainActivity reference inside SettingActivity MainSettingsFragment. 
Activity is meant for to show the UI and you need to keep your business logic out side of activity.If you want to communicate between fragment and parent activity (Host Activity) you could use interface approach.

If you want to access SignleDatabase reference in Setting Activity.
create Helper class to access database reference.

Comment: "outside Activity", where exactly?. I'm new to Android. Should I create another class?

Comment: Create Singleton helper class which holds the SignalDatabase class reference and you could use that in in any activity class.